# findstr issue with multiple lines returned for containing part of search string

Tags: batch-file, findstr

Trying to find line in a file but an having an issue with the literal search string.  When search for a string it is returning multiple line that where the search string is only part of the line.  As an example, I am looking up comp1 in a list of computers and i am getting comp1 and comp1a being returned.  Is there a way to just return the first and not the second, or is this a limitation of findstr.  Code below

```
For /f %%a in (%home%\text.txt) do call :look1 %%a

:look1
 set lookup=%1
 findstr /i /c:%lookup% %home%\data.csv >> %home%\final.csv
 exit /b
```

Edited to include sample of data.csv

Data.csv

date,comp,os,application

date,comp1,os,application

date,comp1a,os,application

date,comp2,os,application

Comment: Include the leading and trailing commas in your search term.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest

```
FINDSTR /r "^comp, ,comp$ ,comp," <qfindrsl.txt
```

would be the way to go. This matches on any of the regex expressions "^comp," (`comp,` at the start of the line), ",comp," (or this string) or ",comp$" (`,comp` at end-of-line.)

---

Edit : I put the data in `qfindrsl.txt`. That worked both with my test data and with the sample data provided.

If the data will not contain the target string at either the start or end of lines, this could be simplified to

```
FINDSTR /r ",comp," <qfindrsl.txt
```

Comment: I should probably have put that data.csv file has the computer name in  a line with lots of other data and it is not the first or last thing in the line.

Comment: Representative sample data often clarifies matters. You can edit your question to include this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regexp terms to limit the find filter:

`^` indicates the start of a line
`$` indicates the end of a line

```
 findstr /r "^comp1$" "filename.txt"
```

Another way is to use `/b` and `/e` in findstr